# Vulkan setting primitive topology dynamically causes crash

Tags: c++, rendering, vulkan

When creating the graphics pipeline I have set

```
VkPipelineDynamicStateCreateInfo.pDynamicStates = { VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY };
```

(setting it to `VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_EXT` doesn't make a difference, they are both the same value on my computer) and enabled the `extendedDynamicState` feature when creating a VkDevice:

```
uint32_t deviceExtensionCount = 1;
const char* deviceExtensions[] = { "VK_KHR_swapchain", "VK_EXT_extended_dynamic_state" };
const float queuePriority[] = { 1.0f };

VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures features;
vkGetPhysicalDeviceFeatures(s_VkData.PhysicalDevice, &features);

VkPhysicalDeviceExtendedDynamicStateFeaturesEXT featuresEXT{};
featuresEXT.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_EXTENDED_DYNAMIC_STATE_FEATURES_EXT;
featuresEXT.extendedDynamicState = VK_TRUE;

VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures2 features2{};
features2.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_FEATURES_2;
features2.features = features;
features2.pNext = &featuresEXT;

VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo queueInfo[1] = {};
queueInfo[0].sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_QUEUE_CREATE_INFO;
queueInfo[0].queueFamilyIndex = s_VkData.QueueFamily;
queueInfo[0].queueCount = 1;
queueInfo[0].pQueuePriorities = queuePriority;

VkDeviceCreateInfo deviceInfo{};
deviceInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_CREATE_INFO;
deviceInfo.queueCreateInfoCount = sizeof(queueInfo) / sizeof(queueInfo[0]);
deviceInfo.pQueueCreateInfos = queueInfo;
deviceInfo.enabledExtensionCount = deviceExtensionCount;
deviceInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = deviceExtensions;
deviceInfo.pNext = &features2;
VkResult result = vkCreateDevice(PhysicalDevice, &deviceInfo, s_VkData.Allocator, &s_VkData.Device);
CheckVkResult(result);
```

But when I call `vkCmdSetPrimitiveTopology` or `vkCmdSetPrimitiveTopologyEXT` when recording a command buffer I get a access violation exception. My command buffer is valid (checked this with visual studio's debugger) and I am not getting any validation errors. Loading `vkCmdSetPrimitiveTopologyEXT` with `vkGetInstanceProcAddr` does not change the result of this.

Comment: It's not an instance extension; why would you use `vkGetInstanceProcAddr`?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling functions that are not part of Vulkan Core 1.0. And unless you do something to get them loaded, calling them will cause a crash because they don't have valid function pointers.

There are three ways to fix this:

- You use the core functions like `vkCmdSetPrimitiveTopology` (no EXT suffix). If so, you need to create your Vulkan instance with an API version where those functions are part of the core. That would be `VK_API_VERSION_1_3` and enable the core feature. Then the function pointers will be available as core functions. Note that this will only work on devices that support Vulkan 1.3 and up.
- You use the extension functions like `vkCmdSetPrimitiveTopologyEXT´ and manually load the function pointers. For this you enable the extension, the extension feature and then use` vkGetInstanceProcAddr` to get a valid function pointer.
- You use a meta loader like [volk](https://github.com/zeux/volk), which will take care of loading function pointers for you.

Comment: I have already tried using `vkCmdSetPrimitiveTopologyEXT` with the extension (as stated in the question)

Comment: Then why do use `vkGetInstanceProcAddr`? And how do you verify that you have a valid function pointer?